# Channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(array)) retrieve another value when clicking the button again

Tags: java

I have implemented Android App - Server side application. The Android app communicate with the server to get authtenticated by the smart card. When I click a button in the App a TCP connection is built and messages are being exchanged until the protocol ends so far so good. Currently I am facing problem when I click the button in the app again. The same process is beig passed through 
but the retrieved data from the smart card are different.

In the SmartCard class --> forwardMessage():

--> First button clicking in the Android App --> first clientSocket:

I am getting this byte `[0, -92, 2, 12, 2, 0, 2]` array as in the screenshot and when calling `channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(array));` I am getting the right response `[-112,0]`

--> Second button clicking in the Android App --> second clientSocket (without run the server application neu)

I am getting this byte `[0, -92, 2, 12, 2, 0, 2]` array as in the screenshot and when calling `channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(array));` I am getting the right response `[106,-126]`

This result `[106,-126]` should be like the one of the first `clientSocket` also `[-112,0]`. As a result of this retrieved data `[106,-126]` from the smart card  the protocol is not being executed to the end.

I have tried to call the disconnect() of the Card class inside the disconnect() of the SmartCard but I am

I appreciate any help!

**the first clientsocket data**

[image]

[image]

**the second clientsocket data**

[image]
[image]

Android App --> Server  --> Card Reader

**Server class**

```
public class Server {

    private final static int RECEIVE_BUFFER_LENGTH = 512;
    public final static int MESSAGE_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 256;
    private final static int MESSAGE_HEADER_LENGTH = 8;
    private static InputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
    private static OutputStream outputStream = null;
    private static SmartCard smartCard = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(27015);

        System.out.println("SS construction of server socket");
        System.out.println("SS listenting for incoming connection on port 27015");

        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            Server.bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            Server.outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            Server.smartCard = new SmartCard();
            Server.handleConnection();

            Server.bufferedInputStream.close();
            Server.outputStream.close();
            Server.smartCard = null;
            clientSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Smart card instance was deleted ");
            System.out.println("--------------------- Finished  ---------------------------");
        }

    }


        private static void handleConnection() throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer receiveBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Server.RECEIVE_BUFFER_LENGTH);
        int readBytes = 0;
        while (true) {
            readBytes = Server.bufferedInputStream.read(receiveBuffer.array(), receiveBuffer.position(),
                    receiveBuffer.remaining());
            System.out.println("readBytes: " + readBytes);
            if (readBytes < 0) {
                break;
            }
             //Here I am reading the received bytes and communicating with the Smart card.

            }
        }

    }


}
```

**SmartCard**

```
public class SmartCard {
    public Card card;
    private String protocol;

    public void connect(String preferredProtocol) {
        Card cardTemp = null;
        this.protocol = preferredProtocol;
        try {

            TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
            List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
            CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
            System.out.println("Reader name: " + terminal.getName());
            if (preferredProtocol.equals(ProtocolType.SC_T0.getProtocolName())) {
                cardTemp = terminal.connect(preferredProtocol);

            } else if (preferredProtocol.equals(ProtocolType.SC_T1.getProtocolName())) {
                cardTemp = terminal.connect(preferredProtocol);
            }
            System.out.println("SC connect --> SCARD Protocol " + preferredProtocol);
            this.card = cardTemp;

        } catch (CardException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private boolean isConnect() {
        if (this.card != null) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }


    public void disconnect() throws CardException {
        if (this.isConnect()) {
            this.card = null;
            //this.card.disconnect(false);
            System.out.println("SC disconnect()");

        }
    }


    private void reconnect(String preferredProtocol) {
        if (!this.isConnect()) {
            this.connect(preferredProtocol);

        }
    }

        public byte[] requestATR() {
        ATR atr = this.card.getATR();
        if (atr.getBytes().length > 0xFF) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Package too big, not supported with protocol -> Answer To Test byte array is too big!");
        }
        return atr.getBytes();
    }


    public byte[] forwardMessage(byte[] array) throws CardException {

        try {
            if (!this.isConnect()) {
                this.reconnect(this.protocol);
                System.out.println("SC reconnect()");

            }

            Cg2AapiServer.printData(array, array.length, SmartCard.OPERATOR, Cg2AapiServer.RECEIVE);

            CardChannel channel = this.card.getBasicChannel();

            System.out.println("data from  the client socket: " + Arrays.toString(array));

            ResponseAPDU responseAPDU = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(array));

            byte[] byteArray = responseAPDU.getBytes();

            System.out.println("retrieved data from the smart card: " + Arrays.toString(byteArray));

            if (responseAPDU.getBytes().length > 0xFF) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Package too big, not supported with protocol.");
            }

            Cg2AapiServer.printData(responseAPDU.getBytes(), responseAPDU.getBytes().length, SmartCard.OPERATOR,
                    Cg2AapiServer.TRANSMIT);

            return responseAPDU.getBytes();

        } catch (CardException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it work I had to add the `this.card.disconnect(false);` method to the disconnect() method in the smart Card like this:

```
public void disconnect() throws CardException {
    if (this.isConnect()) {
        // this.card = null;
        this.card.disconnect(false);
        System.out.println("SC disconnect()");

    }
}
```